# What does an Ender 5 look like in its original foam packaging?

Tags: creality-ender-5

When shipped from the factory to retail the Ender 5 comes packaged in a series of layers using shaped foam.

In order to repackage an Ender 5 in its original box (for example, for transport or storage) it must be dismantled and placed back in this foam packaging in a specific order and arrangement.

What does this order and arrangement look like, with pictures if possible.

This is "how do I deconstruct" question, the opposite to "how do I build".

Comment: I haven't looked but there should be some "unboxing" videos on YT, unless they have gone out of fashion these days. They might show how it was packed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch this in reverse:

The "unboxing" ends at [2:45](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0f0kOz9zR0Q&t=165)

Screenshots in reverse order:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Best answer ever.